# First RandomAccessFile initialization slow, subsequently fast

Tags: java, io, randomaccessfile

I've noticed that the first initialization of a `RandomAccessFile` object in Java is much slower than subsequent initializations of `RandomAccessFile` objects to the same file on disk. Is there some background caching that the OS does to make this possible?

Case in point: I'm loading images from disk and allowing the user to flip through them. I was hoping that the bottleneck would be the display of the images, but on first load, the bottleneck was loading of the images (bottleneck was found using JProfiler; `RandomAccessFile<Init>` ~8ms per call). If I flipped back through images I'd already viewed, the calls to `RandomAccessFile<Init>` was only several microseconds.

Has anyone ever seen something like this? Are there any workarounds? A dataset may contain 100,000's of images, so initializing a bunch of dummy `RandomAcessFile` objects may not be feasible.

The line of code for initialization is simply:

`RandomAccessFile fileIn = new RandomAccessFile(abspath, "r");`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! Just to understand, what is it caching, and is there a way around this? Maybe using something other than `RandomAccessFile` would do it, or is this a general problem for I/O?

Comment: If you bypass caching, the subsequent opens of a file will be as slow as the first one, so why would you want that? Caching is not slowing the first time you open a file, it's improving the performance of re-opening the file, by not having to wait for the slow harddrive to read the data.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, not bypassing the caching. I meant, is there a way to not rely on the caching? I.e. is the implementation of `RandomAccessFile` the problem, and is it caching more information than necessary? I'm not too familiar with the intricacies of Java file I/O. I just need fast image reading from different locations in the file. I'll try the `MappedByteBuffer` I've been seeing thrown around in discussions.

Comment: @ScaryWombat The images aren't all loaded at once. They are loaded on demand, which is why I'm experiencing lag. The problem is, I can't predict the order, or the timing of when the images will be loaded, so this has to be done on the fly.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: As @Andreas has already told you, the implementation of caching is the *solution*, not the problem. The implementation of `RandomAccessFile` has nothing to do with it. It is just the thinnest possible wrapper over the native file system calls. Specifically, Java doesn't do any caching of its own. Not that that would be a problem.

Comment: @EJP got it. Thanks for the information, all.

Comment: @Andreas, I'd be happy to use your comment as an answer if you want to create one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the OS caches.

If you bypass the OS caching, the subsequent opens of a file will be as slow as the first one, so why would you want that?

Caching is not slowing the first time you open a file, it's improving the performance of re-opening the file, by not having to wait for the slow harddrive to read the data.